# ¿Como manejar ERROR .Find().Column en VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, búsquedas

Tengo la siguiente linea de código:

```
columna_inicio = Range("4:4").Find(fecha).Column
```

El problema es que si fecha no existe, el programa suelta un error.

¿Como puedo manejar esto?

He intentado usar los Try Catch pero no consigo que funcione. También el On Error Go To... pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar.

¿Alguna ayuda?

La función a  implementar seria algo como:

```
Public Function detectarfecha(fecha)

    Intenta 
    columna_inicio = Range("4:4").Find(fecha).Column

    Si no puede. Intenta 
    'Otra cosa...

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar la instrucción `On Error` de la siguiente forma:

```
Public Function detectarfecha(fecha)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    columna_inicio = Range("4:4").Find(fecha).Column
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    'Lo que necesites.
End Function
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!